# Android : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid audio buffer size

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, audiorecord

I am trying to play audio after immediate recording of audio using audiorecord class. I have searched google & stackoverflow i dint found any solutions. Any help?
here is the code for Audio_Record ....

```
public class Audio_RecordActivity extends Activity {
private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV = ".wav";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE = "record_temp.raw";
private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 16000;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

private AudioRecord recorder = null;
private int bufferSize = 0;
private Thread recordingThread = null;
private boolean isRecording = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setButtonHandlers();
    enableButtons(false);

    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
            RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
}

private void setButtonHandlers() {
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
}

private void enableButton(int id, boolean isEnable) {
    ((Button) findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
}

private void enableButtons(boolean isRecording) {
    enableButton(R.id.btnStart, !isRecording);
    enableButton(R.id.btnStop, isRecording);
}

private String getFilename() {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV);
}

private String getTempFilename() {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    File tempFile = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);

    if (tempFile.exists())
        tempFile.delete();

    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
}

private void startRecording() {
    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

    recorder.startRecording();

    isRecording = true;

    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            writeAudioDataToFile();
        }
    }, "AudioRecorder Thread");

    recordingThread.start();
}

private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
    byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
    String filename = getTempFilename();
    FileOutputStream os = null;

    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int read = 0;

    if (null != os) {
        while (isRecording) {
            read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

            if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read) {
                try {
                    os.write(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void stopRecording() {
    if (null != recorder) {
        isRecording = false;

        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();

        recorder = null;
        recordingThread = null;
    }

    copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(), getFilename());
    deleteTempFile();
}

private void deleteTempFile() {
    File file = new File(getTempFilename());

    file.delete();
}

private void copyWaveFile(String inFilename, String outFilename) {
    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    long totalAudioLen = 0;
    long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
    long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
    int channels = 2;
    long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels / 8;

    byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
        totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
        totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

        AppLog.logString("File size: " + totalDataLen);

        WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

        while (in.read(data) != -1) {
            out.write(data);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void WriteWaveFileHeader(FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
        long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels, long byteRate)
        throws IOException {

    byte[] header = new byte[44];

    header[0] = 'R'; // RIFF/WAVE header
    header[1] = 'I';
    header[2] = 'F';
    header[3] = 'F';
    header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
    header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[8] = 'W';
    header[9] = 'A';
    header[10] = 'V';
    header[11] = 'E';
    header[12] = 'f'; // 'fmt ' chunk
    header[13] = 'm';
    header[14] = 't';
    header[15] = ' ';
    header[16] = 16; // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
    header[17] = 0;
    header[18] = 0;
    header[19] = 0;
    header[20] = 1; // format = 1
    header[21] = 0;
    header[22] = (byte) channels;
    header[23] = 0;
    header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
    header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
    header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8); // block align
    header[33] = 0;
    header[34] = RECORDER_BPP; // bits per sample
    header[35] = 0;
    header[36] = 'd';
    header[37] = 'a';
    header[38] = 't';
    header[39] = 'a';
    header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
    header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

    out.write(header, 0, 44);
}

private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnStart: {
            AppLog.logString("Start Recording");

            enableButtons(true);
            startRecording();

            break;
        }
        case R.id.btnStop: {
            AppLog.logString("Start Recording");

            enableButtons(false);
            stopRecording();

            break;
        }
        }
    }
};
}
```

I am getting error as shown below logcat file.

logcat error

```
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid audio buffer size.
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.media.AudioRecord.audioBuffSizeCheck(AudioRecord.java:333)
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.media.AudioRecord.<init>(AudioRecord.java:230)
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at audio.xxx.Audio_RecordActivity.startRecording(Audio_RecordActivity.java:88)
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at  audio.xxx.Audio_RecordActivity.access$1(Audio_RecordActivity.java:85)
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at audio.xxx.Audio_RecordActivity$1.onClick(Audio_RecordActivity.java:258)
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-18 16:51:04.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please help me out.. what buffer size should i use. I use 4096 then too showing same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you try with this code its can works fine..

```
    public class Audio_RecordActivity extends Activity {
private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 8000;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
private AudioRecord recorder = null;
private Thread recordingThread = null;
private boolean isRecording = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setButtonHandlers();
    enableButtons(false);

    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
            RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);

    System.out.println("BUFFER SIZE VALUE IS " + bufferSize);

}
private void setButtonHandlers() {
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
}

private void enableButton(int id, boolean isEnable) {
    ((Button) findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
}

private void enableButtons(boolean isRecording) {
    enableButton(R.id.btnStart, !isRecording);
    enableButton(R.id.btnStop, isRecording);
}

int BufferElements2Rec = 1024; // want to play 2048 (2K) since 2 bytes we use only 1024
int BytesPerElement = 2; // 2 bytes in 16bit format

private void startRecording() {

    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, BufferElements2Rec*BytesPerElement);

    recorder.startRecording();
    isRecording = true;

    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            writeAudioDataToFile();

        }
    }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
    recordingThread.start();
}

private byte[] short2byte(short[] sData)
{
    int shortArrsize= sData.length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[shortArrsize*2];

    for (int i=0; i < shortArrsize; i++)
    {
        bytes[i*2] = (byte) (sData[i] & 0x00FF);
        bytes[(i*2)+1] = (byte) (sData[i] >> 8);
        sData[i] = 0;
    }
    return bytes;

 }

  private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
    // Write the output audio in byte

    String filePath = "/sdcard/voice8K16bitmono.pcm";
    short sData[] = new short[BufferElements2Rec];

    FileOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (isRecording) {
        // gets the voice output from microphone to byte format

        recorder.read(sData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);

        try {
            // // writes the data to file from buffer
            // // stores the voice buffer
            byte bData[] = short2byte(sData);
            os.write(bData, 0, BufferElements2Rec*BytesPerElement);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

    try {
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

      private void stopRecording() {
    // stops the recording activity

    if (null != recorder) {
        isRecording = false;

        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();

        recorder = null;
        recordingThread = null;
    }
}

private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnStart: {
            enableButtons(true);
            startRecording();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.btnStop: {
            enableButtons(false);
            stopRecording();
            break;
        }
        }
    }
     };

    @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Audio Recording and Playing it refer this Link [Samples](http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/checkout)
Download the samples and use Audio Recoding Code . It is working great.

Comment: I am trying this sample code only which you have said.. its not working with me.. can you figure it out what I am doing wrong thier.